# Cannot install FunctX in eXist-db

Tags: exist-db, functx

I just installed the latest stable eXist-db version 5.2.0.

I have a project that uses FunctX XQuery Function Library, but when I try to install it in the eXist Package Manager I get the following error:

```
exerr:ERROR expath repository is not available. [at line 176, column 32, source: /db/apps/packageservice/modules/apputil.xql] In function: apputil:remove(xs:string)
[130:20:/db/apps/packageservice/modules/apputil.xql] apputil:install-from-repo(xs:string?, xs:anyURI?, xs:anyURI, xs:string?) [68:40:/db/apps/packageservice/modules/apputil.xql].

expath repository is not available.
```

I have tried installing both through the "Available" packages in the Package Manager and also by manually uploading the FunctX xar file. I have also tried with both FunctX version 1.0 and 1.0.1.

I am able to install other packages.

Comment: Just to be sure about your setup: Simply including the module with `import module namespace functx="http://www.functx.com";` in your XQuery file doesn't work? Just asking because FunctX is usually shipped and you don't have to install it manually.

Comment: You're right, I think the reason why I could't install it is that it was already installed. This was not the case the last time I had to install eXist some years ago. What confused me was the misleading error message and the fact that the package was listed in the "Available" tab in the Dashboard rather than "Installed". This seems like an error.
Anyway, if you write an answer I will accept it.